# How LightGBM deal with a new categorical value in the test set

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, train

Suppose I have the training data set $(X, y)$ where $X$ is my feature space $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. Let $x_1$ be a categorical feature column. In my test set, if the feature $x_1$ takes a new categorical value that does not exist in my training data set (i.e. one row in $x_1$ has a categorical value that was not in the train data set). How does LightGBM handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LightGBM will not handle a new categorical value very elegantly. The level of elegance will depend a bit on the way that the feature is encoded to begin with. (For that matter most automatic methods of handling categorical variables will also fail.)

More details:
Formally ["*categorical features must be encoded as non-negative integers*"](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Advanced-Topics.html). If the new feature value for feature `x1` is encoded as a `5` and in training set we had features `{1, .., 4}` then we are "almost OK". We will have some minor performance degradation in our test set but our predictions for sample instances with categories `{1, .., 4}` are going to fine; feature values `5` will suffer somewhat as they will treated as feature value `4`. Unfortunately in the same scenario if our new feature value for feature `x1` is encoded as a `2` most of our  existing feature `x1` categories will be messed up because they will be shifted. Now how/why can this later point happen? Python's `pandas` as well as R's factor variables usually (i.e. by default) create categories in lexicographic order. If therefore we had `x1` features values `{a,c,d,c,d,a}` those would be used as: `{0,1,2,1,2,0}` but if our test set was like `{a,b,c,d}` those would be translated as `{0,1,2,3}`, i.e. what we thought as being `d` in our training set now is `c` in our test set.

Work-around: Use [target encoding](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/target-encoding.html). Simplify things a bit, we create a numeric feature `x1_num` with the (regularised) mean response variable `y` per category of the categorical variable `x1`; we then use `x1_num` instead of `x1`. There are quite a few ways of performing that regularised mean estimation (e.g. see the Python package [`category_encoders`](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/) for more than a half-a-dozen of them). After doing this target encoding step unseen/new `x1` values are assigned our prior estimate value for the feature `x1_num`. This prior estimate might be a dynamically computed variable (e.g. the mean or the median of our response variable `y` (or maybe a distinct combination of other explanatory variables - check out for example the [`dirty_cat`](https://dirty-cat.github.io/stable/index.html) which handles typos, etc. in a super smart way)) or simply a value we set manually.

Comment: A small technical caveat: LightGBM, when training, performs what is called [Maximum Homogeneity Grouping](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1958.10501479) for the levels of a categorical feature. This is briefly explained [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Features.html#optimal-split-for-categorical-features); the main consequence is that we do not use splits based on how our categorical variables are encoded directly but rather based on their weights in our tree learner. Unfortunately this does not change the fact that our (integer) labels will be messed up.